# Are there any RIM Blackberry clients for Jira?

Tags: blackberry, jira

I want to access Jira through my Blackberry, but I'm not very interested in accessing web client through Blackberry browser. Are there any native solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PuguaSoft LLC is developing a BlackBerry application for JIRA called PocketJIRA. It's still in development, but we're hoping to release a beta version for testing soon. For more information, please visit http://www.pocketjira.com.

Answer (score 0):

Can't find any BlackBerry JIRA application. But I've found out there are [RPC services in JIRA](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/JIRA+RPC+Services;jsessionid=1047AC7DFEE5452657EF30D005A58E1D), so it's possible to implement such application with limited client functionality.