# How to create new and creative Blackberry application?

Tags: blackberry, startup

I'm fresh blackberry application developer. I want to create some new and creative blackberry application which can be used in enterprise application. But I don't have a clear idea about how to start and which idea i can take and proceed.

- If you have any idea about how to start and create a new application?
- From where we can know about existing ERP application for blackberry?
- Other than enterprise application in which field we can focus in blackberry application developement?

Comment: Are you asking if anyone can suggest what type/idea for an application you should build?

Comment: yes kane i m expecting what type of application i can develope?..i m new to this field so i don't know what type of application i can create and i also don't have a idea about what are the existing application avilable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Types of application

- social (so/twitter/wiki)
- games
- information (weather/news/blogs)
- communication (irc/chat/email, after all that's what blackberry is for)
- audio (radio/music/podcast)
- maps (googlemaps/persistent)
- photo, video
- many, many more...

### New ideas generator

There are several good methods how to come up with new ideas:

- Mix up. Take two apps, technologies, whathever, and mix up them. Ex: take photo, add gps, put on Google Earth - voula, [Panoramio](http://www.panoramio.com/). Or game + email. Or clock + gps. etc.
- Port. Yes, maybe there is something on iphone, wm, or even better, J2ME what you woul'd like to port to BlackBerry. Of course, with all BB specific, and maybe with some tuneup.
  [BlackBerry Game Development Tips - Not Just Another Port!](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Developer-s-Blog/BlackBerry-Game-Development-Tips-Not-Just-Another-Port/ba-p/330556#A127)
- What you need from BB? If your friends have BB, ask them, what app they would find useful on BB. It's great if you write something for youreself, test it, use it for a time, making it perfect, and then bring it to the world.
- Mobile client. Take a look at all social/svn/wiki/tracking etc network services, sure some of them may have a BB mobile client. Just like this:
  [Are there any RIM Blackberry clients for Jira?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142161/1149365#1149365)
- Good old stuff. Maybe some old digger game? Or FAR manager? It may be crazy, or not. Just remember that it's BB mobile, and remember what it can.
- System utilites? How many there are for BB? Is there a need?

BTW, [O'Reilly's Mind Hacks](http://www.mindhacks.com/book/) is nice.

And of course when you will have an idea about app, search in google, if it's not created yet.

Have a fun coding ;)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Become fresh and creative
Step 2: Get fun application idea!
Step 3: Write software

The title of your answer makes it sound like you need advice on coming up with ideas. You should probably change it to something more meaningful... Unless that's what you *do* mean, in which case, I would go look at other applications, and find something that none of them does. Then make an application that does that thing you think the rest of them are lacking.

Start [here.](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/services/appworld/?)

Answer (score 0):

Why not comb through the Android and iTunes marketplaces and see what apps are out there that don't have solid equivalents on the BBOS platform?  For instance, I would like to see some more utilities aimed at system administrators.  The SSH client offerings aren't the greatest.  Also, you would maybe write things like a github app or an app to make it easier to track the progress of answers to your SO questions.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be something you love, something you are passionate about.

In the Blackberry world, there are a number of ways you can develop your software. You can create a J2ME app or you can create a native app. From what i understand they have now added a capability of running Android apps on BlackBerry.
If it is your first time developing for the mobile world, i would suggest to start with a simple things, J2ME has its upsides (i have started my way in this technology) but it also have its downsides. If you already know Java, i would suggest to start with android development (where you do not have porting issues and the testing is much easier)

Good Luck.